# Failed to build spark2.4.3 against hadoop 3.2.0

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, bigdata

I'm building `spark 2.4.3` to make it compatible to latest `hadoop 3.2.0`.

The source code is downloaded from https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/spark/spark-2.4.3/spark-2.4.3.tgz

Build command is `./build/mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-3.2 -Dhadoop.version=3.2.0 -DskipTests clean package`

The build result is:

```
[INFO] Spark Project Parent POM ........................... SUCCESS [  1.761 s]
[INFO] Spark Project Tags ................................. SUCCESS [  1.221 s]
[INFO] Spark Project Sketch ............................... SUCCESS [  0.551 s]
[INFO] Spark Project Local DB ............................. SUCCESS [  0.608 s]
[INFO] Spark Project Networking ........................... SUCCESS [  1.558 s]
[INFO] Spark Project Shuffle Streaming Service ............ SUCCESS [  0.631 s]
[INFO] Spark Project Unsafe ............................... SUCCESS [  0.444 s]
[INFO] Spark Project Launcher ............................. SUCCESS [  2.501 s]
[INFO] Spark Project Core ................................. SUCCESS [ 13.536 s]
[INFO] Spark Project ML Local Library ..................... SUCCESS [  0.549 s]
[INFO] Spark Project GraphX ............................... SUCCESS [  1.614 s]
[INFO] Spark Project Streaming ............................ SUCCESS [  3.332 s]
[INFO] Spark Project Catalyst ............................. SUCCESS [ 14.271 s]
[INFO] Spark Project SQL .................................. SUCCESS [ 13.008 s]
[INFO] Spark Project ML Library ........................... SUCCESS [  7.923 s]
[INFO] Spark Project Tools ................................ SUCCESS [  0.187 s]
[INFO] Spark Project Hive ................................. SUCCESS [  6.664 s]
[INFO] Spark Project REPL ................................. SUCCESS [  1.285 s]
[INFO] Spark Project YARN Shuffle Service ................. SUCCESS [  4.824 s]
[INFO] Spark Project YARN ................................. SUCCESS [  3.020 s]
[INFO] Spark Project Assembly ............................. SUCCESS [  1.558 s]
[INFO] Spark Integration for Kafka 0.10 ................... SUCCESS [  1.411 s]
[INFO] Kafka 0.10+ Source for Structured Streaming ........ SUCCESS [  1.573 s]
[INFO] Spark Project Examples ............................. SUCCESS [  1.702 s]
[INFO] Spark Integration for Kafka 0.10 Assembly .......... SUCCESS [  5.969 s]
[INFO] Spark Avro ......................................... SUCCESS [  0.702 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:32 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-07-31T18:56:24+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The requested profile "hadoop-3.2" could not be activated because it does not exist.
```

According to my expectation, an all-in-one compress file like `spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz` would be generated under build directory, just like the binary file that can be downloaded from official site, https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/spark/spark-2.4.3/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz.

How can I remove the warning `The requested profile "hadoop-3.2" could not be activated because it does not exist`, what does it mean?

Comment: Hi @Eugene, do you find a solution to build  a working spark 2.4.x with an Hadoop 3+? I am trying to do the same but unfortunately, after building it, it seems that guava versions remain incompatible.

Comment: @AxelBorja I reverted to Spark2.3.x against Hadoop2.8.x. Thanks for reaching me but I made no progress on this thread.

Comment: Ok Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Yes, I have the same issue building spark 2.4.7 with hadoop 3.2.2, java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caution: What you are trying to do could result in very unstable environment if you don't know what you are doing.

That being said, spark 2.4.x stable release does not have profile `hadoop-3.2`, it has `hadoop-3.1`.

You will need to pull code from master to achieve what you want to achieve.

If your sole intention is to make `spark 2.4.3` compatible with `hadoop 3.2`, you could look at profile in master along with relevant changes and cherrypick those into your own workspace.

Comment: Thanks you man. If hadoop-3.1 is supported, I plan to build the spark compatible with 3.1.2, like `./build/mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-3.1 -Dhadoop.version=3.1.2 -DskipTests clean package`, by the way. How do you know that 3.1 version is supported by Spark 2.4.x?

Comment: Take a look at https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-help-plugin/all-profiles-mojo.html You an run `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:3.2.0:all-profiles` to know all the profiles under current project.

Comment: Also, you can simply take a look at `pom.xml` to know more about build related features.